# Can't output data in page

Tags: python, django

i have 2 tables in DB wallet(id,name) and balance(id,wallet_id)

i need table consisting of 2 cells (post,date)

where will all wallets in first cell and them balance in second

```
{% for wallets1 in wallets %}
<tr>
  {% for balance1 in balance %} 
  {% if balance1.wallet_id == wallets1.id %}
  <td> {{ balance1.balance }}</td>
  {% endif %} {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

if we have balance of coin we print balance 
if balance1.wallet_id need print "0"

The difficulty next. If i do that

```
{% for wallets1 in wallets %}
<tr>
  {% for balance1 in balance %} 
  {% if balance1.wallet_id == wallets1.id %}
  <td> {{ balance1.balance }}</td>
  {% else %}
  <td> 0</td>
  {% endif %} {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

zero will be printed many times

views

```
wallets = Wallet.objects.all()
balance = User_balance.objects.filter(user_id= user.id)
args['wallets'] = wallets
args['balance'] = balance
return render_to_response("coins.html", args, user.id)
```

model

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User_balance(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    wallet_id = models.IntegerField()
    balance = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: maby exist something like: if loop on last element and nothing found print 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must annotate balance in your view like this

```
wallers = Wallet.objects.all().annotate(total_balance=models.Count('balance'))
...
return render(request, 'template.html', {"wallets": wallets})
```

then in your html print wallets like this

```
<table>
    <tr><th>wallet</th><th>balance</th></tr>
    {% for wallet in wallets %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ wallet.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ wallet.total_balance|default:0 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post your view nor models so we have to assume a couple things but basically you're doing it wrong. Since balances have a foreign key on wallets, you don't have to loop over all balances for each wallets, you can just [use the reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

```
{% for wallet in wallets %}
<tr>
  {% for balance in wallet.balance_set.all  %} 
    <td> {{ balance.balance }}</td>
  {% else %}
    <td> 0</td>
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what will happen if the associated element is not.I can print "0"?

Comment: There may be no records in the database. ie the user does not have it. what relationship with not exist record?

Comment: Sorry but my crystal ball is out for repair... Seriously, am I supposed to guess what your models and views look like ? But anyway: if a queryset is empty the loop just doesn't execute...